# <cfmediaplayer> how to pause the player through javascript calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, coldfusion

I'm implementing the Coldfusion `<cfmediaplayer>` tag for playing flash videos on a touch-screen based local web application.  I am aware that by default the user is able to simply tap the video itself to pause/play the video.

I am also aware that `<cfmediaplayer>` has a built-in control panel through the use of the `controlbar="true"` attribute, but the problem is the buttons are way too small for a touchscreen and I don't want the user to be able to access any other controls.

To combat this, I disabled the controlbar and tried to add a custom play/pause button below the player to essentially mimic the actions of touching the video itself.  My problem is that I cannot find a way to simply **pause** the video... the only Javascript functions I could find are:

`ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.stopPlay` and `ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.startPlay`

The issue is that `ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.stopPlay` restarts the video from the beginning and not from where the video currently is.

Is there any way around this?  As a last resort I will simply stick the play/pause button in the corner of the video to hint to the user that they can touch the video screen to enable those actions, but I'd rather have a separate button so as not to obstruct the user...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you call `ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.startPlay` while the video is playing?  Does it pause?

Comment: Hi Miguel. Unfortunately, calling `ColdFusion.Mediaplayer.startPlay` while the video is playing does nothing :(

Comment: Sorry @Shaun it was just a wild guess. I did some searching but have not found any _pause_ function either. Are you running ColdFusion 9 or 10?  I know that some enhancements were made to `cfmediaplayer` in CF 10.

Comment: @Miguel-F I am currently running CF9 so that may be the issue - I hadn't thought of that.  I'll have to review the CF10 documentation to see if they have solved this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: you would think something as basic as _pause_ would be included, but I'm not finding it. I actually looked inside the `cfmediaplayer.js` that ships with CF 9 and did not find any _pause_ function. Obviously the embedded player can do it but I don't see the matching JavaScript function. Anyway, [here is a enhancements page that I found for CF 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851852cc9f7d1353e88b409-7fed.html). Under "Player controls" it mentions that CF 9 supports Play/Pause but I assume they mean the embedded player (not in script).

Comment: @Miguel-F I see your point.  Thank you for your help in finding this.  I may have to just use another player for my videos - I was surprised as well to not find a script pause functionality.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran across the [cfMediaPlayer project on RIAForge](http://cfmediaplayer.riaforge.org/). It is a _"ColdFusion custom tag wrapper to display FLV, MP3, MP4 and AAC files using the JW FLV Player™ with one line of code"_. It may give you more control. See the [JW Player API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference) which includes a pause function. **Note there may be a cost associated with using that player**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Miguel-F for his help.

We have figured out that `<cfmediaplayer>` does NOT have pausing functionality by default, and only has the ability to Play or Stop the video entirely and restart from the beginning of the clip.

Looks like workarounds are required (or other methods of showing the videos entirely).